# Не работает скрипт транслита

Tags: php

Добрый день) Знаю что это убогий пример (пишется как тренировка, посмотреть как работает) , но если будет корректно работать этот фрагмент, то не думаю что будет большим затруднением все корректно дописать, и прилепить пару функций, чтобы скрипт нормально отрабатывал)
В общем, код выводит какую-то кракозябру)

```
    <?php
function translit ($str) {

$str = strtr($str,"абвгдежзиклмнопрстуфхцы",
                  "abvgdejziklmnoprstyfhcu" 
        );
// $str = strtr($str, [ё => yo, й => ui, ч => ch, ш => sh, щ => sha, ю => you, я => ai  ]);
return $str;
}
var_dump(translit("кино"));
?>
```

*Результат: ufutu�u�*
Функция strtr - работает по-байтово. Анг - 1 байт, русские - 2 байта. Var_dump - выводит 8 символов. 
Как тогда это пофиксить?
Или вариант только - все массивом сделать?

Comment: Во втором комментарии к статье всё написано http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php
Да, нужен ассоциативный массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function translit($input) {
  $iso9_table = array(
    'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Ѓ' => 'G',
    'Ґ' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Є' => 'YE',
    'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'Ѕ' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J',
    'Ј' => 'J', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'YI', 'К' => 'K', 'Ќ' => 'K',
    'Л' => 'L', 'Љ' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'Њ' => 'N',
    'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T',
    'У' => 'U', 'Ў' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'TS',
    'Ч' => 'CH', 'Џ' => 'DH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SHH', 'Ъ' => '',
    'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA',
    'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'ѓ' => 'g',
    'ґ' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'є' => 'ye',
    'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'ѕ' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j',
    'ј' => 'j', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'к' => 'k', 'ќ' => 'k',
    'л' => 'l', 'љ' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'њ' => 'n',
    'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
    'у' => 'u', 'ў' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'ts',
    'ч' => 'ch', 'џ' => 'dh', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'shh', 'ъ' => '',
    'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
  );
  return strtr($input, $iso9_table);
}
var_dump(translit('Рабочий скрипт транслита'));
?>
```

Таблицу символов смотреть [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9).

Answer (score 0):

1. Строку с буквами кириллицы режем при помощи регэкспов (`preg_split('\\u'...`) - получаем массив;
2. Строку с буквами латиницы режем при помощи `str_split()`;
3. Дополняем массивы буквами, которые меняются на две или более латинских;
4. Заменяем буквы в строке при помощи `str_replace()`

И, кстати, можно воспользоваться расширением php-intl.

Comment: Слишком сложно!

Comment: @Visman Что тут сложного?