# Необходимо создать функцию, которая будет переводить текст на транслит

Tags: php

Пытался разными способами, но никак не получатеся. помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста:)

```
function WriteTranslite($myString){
        $transliteSheet = array(
            "а" => "a",
            "б" => "b",
            "в" => "v",
            "г" => "g",
            "д" => "d",
            "е" => "e",
            "ё" => "e",
            "ж" => "zh",
            "з" => "z",
            "и" => "i",
            "й" => "i",
            "к" => "k",
            "л" => "l",
            "м" => "m",
            "н" => "n",
            "о" => "o",
            "п" => "p",
            "р" => "r",
            "с" => "s",
            "т" => "t",
            "у" => "u",
            "ф" => "f",
            "х" => "h",
            "ц" => "c",
            "ч" => "ch",
            "ш" => "sh",
            "щ" => "sh'",
            "ъ" => "'",
            "ы" => "bl",
            "ь" => "'",
            "э" => "e",
            "ю" => "yu",
            "я" => "ya"
        );

        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($myString); $i++){
            foreach ($transliteSheet as $key => $value) {
                if($myString{$i} == $key){
                    $myString{$i} = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $myString;
    }

    $myString = "аывпва";
    echo WriteTranslite($myString);
```

Comment: Не работает ибо что-то не так с кодировкой, вывод одной буквы: `Array ( [0] => � [1] => � )`.

Comment: `strlen()` для работы с однобайтовыми кодировками. `$myString{$i}` берет не символ, а байт. А ответ тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795054/186083 есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуюсь таким вариантом:

```
function translit($value) {
  $t_arr = array(
    'cyr' => array(
      'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я','а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я'
    ), 
    'lat' => array(
      'A','B','V','G','D','E','JO','ZH','Z','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U','F','H','C','CH','SH','SHH','','I','','JE','JU','JA','a','b','v','g','d','e','jo','zh','z','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f','h','c','ch','sh','shh','','i','','je','ju','ja'
    )
  );

  return str_replace($t_arr['cyr'], $t_arr['lat'], $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь такой функцией:

```
function translit(w)
{
    var v=0;

    var tr='a b v g d e ["zh","j"] z i y k l m n o p r s t u f h c ch sh ["shh","shch"] ~ y ~ e yu ya ~ ["jo","e"]'.split(' ');
    var ww=''; w=w.toLowerCase();
    for(i=0; i<w.length; ++i) {
     cc=w.charCodeAt(i); ch=(cc>=1072?tr[cc-1072]:w[i]);
     if(ch.length<3) ww+=ch; else ww+=eval(ch)[v];
    }

    var trn=ww.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'-').replace(/[-]{2,}/gim, '-').replace( /^\-+/g, '').replace( /\-+$/g, '');

    return trn;
 }
```

Comment: Отлично. Вот только это не PHP ))

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой вариант

```
function string_translit($string, $type = 'iso') {
    $gost = array(
       "Є"=>"EH","І"=>"I","і"=>"i","№"=>"#","є"=>"eh",
       "А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G","Д"=>"D",
       "Е"=>"E","Ё"=>"JO","Ж"=>"ZH",
       "З"=>"Z","И"=>"I","Й"=>"JJ","К"=>"K","Л"=>"L",
       "М"=>"M","Н"=>"N","О"=>"O","П"=>"P","Р"=>"R",
       "С"=>"S","Т"=>"T","У"=>"U","Ф"=>"F","Х"=>"H",
       "Ц"=>"C","Ч"=>"CH","Ш"=>"SH","Щ"=>"SHH","Ъ"=>"'",
       "Ы"=>"Y","Ь"=>"","Э"=>"EH","Ю"=>"YU","Я"=>"YA",
       "а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d",
       "е"=>"e","ё"=>"jo","ж"=>"zh",
       "з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"jj","к"=>"k","л"=>"l",
       "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
       "с"=>"s","т"=>"t","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h",
       "ц"=>"c","ч"=>"ch","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"shh","ъ"=>"",
       "ы"=>"y","ь"=>"","э"=>"eh","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya"
    );
    $iso = array(
       "Є"=>"YE","І"=>"I","Ѓ"=>"G","і"=>"i","№"=>"#","є"=>"ye","ѓ"=>"g",
       "А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G","Д"=>"D",
       "Е"=>"E","Ё"=>"YO","Ж"=>"ZH",
       "З"=>"Z","И"=>"I","Й"=>"J","К"=>"K","Л"=>"L",
       "М"=>"M","Н"=>"N","О"=>"O","П"=>"P","Р"=>"R",
       "С"=>"S","Т"=>"T","У"=>"U","Ф"=>"F","Х"=>"X",
       "Ц"=>"C","Ч"=>"CH","Ш"=>"SH","Щ"=>"SHH","Ъ"=>"'",
       "Ы"=>"Y","Ь"=>"","Э"=>"E","Ю"=>"YU","Я"=>"YA",
       "а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d",
       "е"=>"e","ё"=>"yo","ж"=>"zh",
       "з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"j","к"=>"k","л"=>"l",
       "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
       "с"=>"s","т"=>"t","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"x",
       "ц"=>"c","ч"=>"ch","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"shh","ъ"=>"",
       "ы"=>"y","ь"=>"","э"=>"e","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya"
    );
    switch ($type) {        
        case 'gost':
            return strtr($string, $gost);
        default: 
            return strtr($string, $iso);
    }
}
```